# multiple column value to single value with IIF condition in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

[image]

Hi Team,
I have a SSRS report like this, the users would like to see the data like the picture below. For Column 2 if the value is N/A the values of column 3 would be in list and separated by comma. and the multiple lines will be converted to only one line where N/A is there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you will want to create row groups for two of your columns. I have assumed they're called Shipment and Description. Then you can use `Join` and [`LookupSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx) to do the CSV aggregation. Similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456984/lookupset-based-on-two-fields-combined-instead-of-one).

Something like this:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!Shipment.Value & "-" & Fields!Description.Value,
                Fields!Shipment.Value & "-" & Fields!Description.Value,
                Fields!PartNumber.Value, "YourDataset"), ",")
```

Comment: Can we use if clause in it?
iif pname = "N/A"
begin
Join(LookupSet(Fields!Description.Value, Fields!Description.Value, Fields!PartNumber.Value, "YourDataset"), ",")
end

Comment: @AshishMandal You could use inline if, but it shouldn't be necessary? All the descriptions that aren't N/A will only have one PartNumber so no list will be created.

Comment: Thanks, FrumRoll.
When i apply the logic you stated at the beginning, it is giving me concat result of all the rows, but the requirement is to get the result for only for the column 1 specific group. is it possible to get the result? please help

Comment: @AshishMandal I've updated my answer, you need to concat your groups prior to applying the filter.